# SSRS/BIDS development setup VS2017

Tags: reporting-services, bids

How can I setup my laptop for SSRS/BIDS report development on Visual Studio 2017? I have tried nothing as I don't work in DevTech.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use SQL Server Data Tools which is available with instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools

Answer (score 0):

These six downloads should get you going:

```
1.[SQL Server 2017 Express edition][1]
2.[SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)][2]
3.[SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services][3]
4.[Visual Studio Installer][4]
5.[Visual Studio Community][5]
6.[Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT)][6]

 [1]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express
 [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15
 [3]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252
 [4]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019
 [5]: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15
 [6]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15
```